# Changing img src with dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Attempting to update an image when selecting various options in a dropdown (in Wordpress).

```
jQuery( window ).ready(function() {

var color;

jQuery("#pa_colour").change(function() {
  color = jQuery(this).val();
}).change();

jQuery(document).on('change', 'select', function() {

if(color=='red') {
    document.getElementById('Image').src = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/red.jpg";
} else if(color=="green") {
    document.getElementById('Image').src = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/green.jpg";
} 
  });

});
```

The 'color' variable appears to get initialized, but when checking it in console, it doesn't receive a value. If I plug in this piece of code manually into the console, the image will change:

```
jQuery("#pa_colour").change(function() {
  color = jQuery(this).val();
}).change();
```

So it seems to be an issue with the variable not getting set - not sure why though.

**Edit:**

Here's my work on [codepen](https://codepen.io/SeanLindsay1/pen/KqQmqJ?editors=1111)

Brought everything into a single handler, which appears to work in codepen but fails to work in Wordpress (this was the same case with my initial attempt). The difference now is that when viewing console on the Wordpress page, the `color` variable comes up as undefined, whereas before it showed an empty string.

Comment: Why do you have two change handlers for the same thing?  What's your markup look like?

Comment: Handle changing the image in the same handler you set the variable in.

Comment: Thanks @NieDzejkob -- I followed your suggestion but still having some issues. Provided a codepen in the original post.

Comment: What is your HTML in the wordpress?

Comment: Just added a 'raw html' element and threw this img tag in:
`<img src="[img url]" width="800" height="800" id="Image"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You're kind creating the same change handler twice, just put it altogether, I assume this will do it?

```
jQuery( window ).ready(function() {

var color;

jQuery("#pa_colour").on('change', 'select', function() {

  color = jQuery(this).val();

  if(color=='red') {
    document.getElementById('Image').src = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/red.jpg";
} else if(color=="green") {
    document.getElementById('Image').src = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/green.jpg";
} 
  });

});
```